# Django Rest - FileUploadView - Unexpected data being added into an Uploaded File

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my FileUploadView class to handle POST request of an uploaded file. The file I am expecting are XML Files in which I use ElementTree to parse through it in fileHandler(). However, when using Postman to send a file through using ('form-data'), I realized that it is attaching some type of header to my uploaded file, which in turn causes the tree parse() to have a syntax error since its reading something that is not of an XML format.

I tried using HTTPie to send the file through, which worked with no issue, the XML Parser parsed it correctly and entered the data into the expected Object.

I then tried to do some TestCases with Django, and tried to test the fileupload. Which caused the parser to have a syntax error again due to having a header attached to the file once more.

```
class UploadTest(APITestCase):
    def test_file_upload(self):
        c = Client()
        with open("/Users/Ren/Desktop/Capstone/Backend/projectB/VMA/testing/Test.xml") as fp:
            c.post('/upload/TestXML.xml', {'filename' : 'Test.xml', 'attachment': fp})
```

My question is: What is causing that header to pop up/be added onto the uploaded file. I'm guessing it has something to do with how I am sending the post request through Postman and the Django TestCase which is different to HTTPie

view.py

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)


    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
        print(request.FILES)
        file_obj = request.FILES['file']
        fileHandler(file_obj)
        return Response(status=204)
```

FileReader.py

```
def fileHandler(file):
    filepath = file.temporary_file_path()
    print(file.read())

    tree = ET.parse(filepath)
    root = tree.getroot()
```

XML File and output when calling file.read()

```
XML I need to read in (Expected Output):
<site host="192.168.212.4" name="http://192.168.212.4" port="80" ssl="false"><alerts><alertitem>\n  <pluginid>10021</pluginid>\n  <alert>X-Content-Type-Options header missing</alert>\n  <riskcode>1</riskcode>\n  <reliability>2</reliability>\n  <riskdesc>Low (Warning)</riskdesc>\n  <desc>The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to \'nosniff\'.\n\tThis allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type.\n\tCurrent (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing.\n\t</desc>\n  <uri>http://192.168.212.4/</uri>\n  <param/>\n  <attack/>\n  <otherinfo/>\n  <solution>Ensure that the application/web server sets the Content-Type header appropriately, and that it sets the X-Content-Type-Options header to \'nosniff\' for all web pages.\n\tIf possible, ensure that the end user uses a standards-compliant and modern web browser that does not perform MIME-sniffing at all, or that can be directed by the web application/web server to not perform MIME-sniffing.\n\t</solution>\n  <reference>\n\t</reference>\n</alertitem>


The Output when running request.FILES['file'].read() --- Current Output
b'----------------------------507481440966899800347275\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="sampleXML.xml"\r\nContent-Type: application/xml\r\n\r\n<site host="192.168.212.4" name="http://192.168.212.4" port="80" ssl="false"><alerts><alertitem>\n  <pluginid>10021</pluginid>\n  <alert>X-Content-Type-Options header missing</alert>\n  <riskcode>1</riskcode>\n  <reliability>2</reliability>\n  <riskdesc>Low (Warning)</riskdesc>\n  <desc>The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to \'nosniff\'.\n\tThis allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type.\n\tCurrent (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing.\n\t</desc>\n  <uri>http://192.168.212.4/</uri>\n  <param/>\n  <attack/>\n  <otherinfo/>\n  <solution>Ensure that the application/web server sets the Content-Type header appropriately, and that it sets the X-Content-Type-Options header to \'nosniff\' for all web pages.\n\tIf possible, ensure that the end user uses a standards-compliant and modern web browser that does not perform MIME-sniffing at all, or that can be directed by the web application/web server to not perform MIME-sniffing.\n\t</solution>\n  <reference>\n\t</reference>\n</alertitem>\n\n  \r\n----------------------------507481440966899800347275--\r\n'
```

Contains the unnecessary: b'----------------------------507481440966899800347275\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="sampleXML.xml"\r\nContent-Type: application/xml\r\n\r\n

Comment: How is that code being sent to the API? Show your frontend code.

Comment: How are you posting your file? this is the standard way to attach files to a POST request body, but Django should remove this part if your POST HTTP headers contain the correct content-type.

Comment: This is what the "Content-Type" header should look like: "multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------507481440966899800347275" so that Django can understand where the file starts.

Comment: Im sending the HTTP POST request through postman, I'm still unfamiliar with postman so this could be the issue. With Postman, I'm sending a form-data with the XML File attached, and nothing else. The content type being sent by a temporary header is "multipart/form-data'boundary=-----------------------" Is this the cause of the issue? since its a temporary header?

Comment: I tried using HTTPie to send the file. And it worked perfectly as intended. So now Im leaning towards postman being the issue - that its writing the header details into the file for somereason, which is causing issues with XML Reader

Answer (score 0):

I played around with code for a bit and made a tiny change into the testCase:

```
class UploadTest(APITestCase):
    def test_file_upload(self):
        c = Client()
        with open("/Users/Ren/Desktop/Capstone/Backend/projectB/VMA/testing/Test.xml") as fp:
            c.post('/upload/TestXML.xml', {'filename' : 'Test.xml', 'attachment': fp})
```

I changed the 
`{'filename' : 'Test.xml', 'attachment': fp}`
to
`{'filename' : b'Test.xml', 'attachment': fp}`

I remember reading it somewhere, unfortunately I do not remember where but... turning the file into "bytes" fixed it...